# Convert str with single and double quotations into int

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, types

What is the best solution to convert a `'"1"'` or `"'1'"` (string) into `1` (int) using python?

**int()** method will return this value error message

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "'1'"
```

if you try `int('"1"')` or `int("'1'")`

The solution that I used is as follow:

```
tmp = '"1"'
tmp = tmp.replace('"', "")
tmp

# output: 1
```

The flaw in this "solution" is that the inner quotation (single/double) matters.

Comment: `tmp = tmp.replace("'", "")replace('"', '')` will replace both

Comment: your best bet is to apply regular expression to extract digits, and convert them to string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use

```
tmp = tmp.strip("'\"")
```

This removes both `'` and `"` from the start/end of  `tmp`.